# Component html out of place

Tags: html, css

I need your help, I'm creating an e-mail template. One of the components I will add to the template is a small pop-up dropdown that will appear when you hover over the text "Total".
My problem is that it's not appearing on the same line. The div with the id "Number1" is appearing below the text "Josh" when it should appear next to it. How do I get on the same line?

Component html out of place.

Note: Afterwards I will add several divs similar to this Number1, below it.

```css
/* -------------------------------------     GLOBAL     A very basic CSS reset ------------------------------------- */

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        /* Let's make sure all tables have defaults */

        table td {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     BODY & CONTAINER ------------------------------------- */

        body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

        .body-wrap {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .container {
            display: block !important;
            max-width: 600px !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            /* makes it centered */
            clear: both !important;
        }

        .content {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     HEADER, FOOTER, MAIN ------------------------------------- */

        .main {
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .content-wrap {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .content-block {
            padding: 0 0 20px;
        }

        .header {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .footer {
            width: 100%;
            clear: both;
            color: #999;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .footer a {
            color: #999;
        }

        .footer p,
        .footer a,
        .footer unsubscribe,
        .footer td {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     TYPOGRAPHY ------------------------------------- */

        h1,
        h2,
        h3 {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            color: #000;
            margin: 40px 0 0;
            line-height: 1.2;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        h4 {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        p,
        ul,
        ol {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        p li,
        ul li,
        ol li {
            margin-left: 5px;
            list-style-position: inside;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     LINKS & BUTTONS ------------------------------------- */

        a {
            color: #1ab394;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .btn-primary {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #1ab394;
            border: solid #1ab394;
            border-width: 5px 10px;
            line-height: 2;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     OTHER STYLES THAT MIGHT BE USEFUL ------------------------------------- */

        .last {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .first {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .aligncenter {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .alignright {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .alignleft {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     ALERTS     Change the class depending on warning email, good email or bad email ------------------------------------- */

        .alert {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 500;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
        }

        .alert a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .alert.alert-warning {
            background: #f8ac59;
        }

        .alert.alert-bad {
            background: #ed5565;
        }

        .alert.alert-good {
            background: #1ab394;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     INVOICE     Styles for the billing table ------------------------------------- */

        .invoice {
            margin: 40px auto;
            text-align: left;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .invoice td {
            padding: 1px 0;
        }

        .invoice .invoice-items {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .invoice .invoice-items td {
            border-top: #eee 1px solid;
            padding-left: 1px;
        }

        .invoice .invoice-items .total td {
            border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE FRIENDLY STYLES ------------------------------------- */

        @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
            h1,
            h2,
            h3,
            h4 {
                font-weight: 600 !important;
                margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 22px !important;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size: 18px !important;
            }
            h3 {
                font-size: 16px !important;
            }
            .container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .content,
            .content-wrap {
                padding: 10px !important;
            }
            .invoice {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        .celulasValores {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .bordas-left {
            border-top-left-radius: 40%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 40%;
        }

        .bordas-right {
            border-top-right-radius: 40%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
        }

        .total {
            border-color: #ddd;
        }

        .tableValores table {
            border-spacing: 5px;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;

        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 360px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 12px 16px;
            z-index: 1;

        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;

        }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  TOTAL:
  <div class="dropdown-content">



    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Josh
            <div aria-label="Basic example" id="Number1">
              <table class="tableValores">
                <tr>
                  <td title="15 Dias" class="celulasValores bordas-left" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center;">16</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores" title="3 Dias" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">6</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores" title="Hoje" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">4</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores bordas-right" title="Último dia" style="padding: 2px 5px;align: center">0</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="alignright" class="total">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
              <table class="tableValores">
                <tr>
                  <td title="Atrasado após a Ação" class="celulasValores bordas-left" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">26</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores" title="Atrasado após a Meta" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">0</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores bordas-right" title="Atrasado após o Vencimento" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">292</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="alignright" class="total">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
              <table class="tableValores">
                <tr>
                  <td title="Aguardando Solicitação" class="celulasValores bordas-left" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">0</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores bordas-right" title="Retificando" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">0</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your name "Josh" inside a table cell `<td>` and everything will go to the correct place.

```
      <td>Josh</td>
```

```css
/* -------------------------------------     GLOBAL     A very basic CSS reset ------------------------------------- */

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        /* Let's make sure all tables have defaults */

        table td {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     BODY & CONTAINER ------------------------------------- */

        body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

        .body-wrap {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .container {
            display: block !important;
            max-width: 600px !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            /* makes it centered */
            clear: both !important;
        }

        .content {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     HEADER, FOOTER, MAIN ------------------------------------- */

        .main {
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .content-wrap {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .content-block {
            padding: 0 0 20px;
        }

        .header {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .footer {
            width: 100%;
            clear: both;
            color: #999;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .footer a {
            color: #999;
        }

        .footer p,
        .footer a,
        .footer unsubscribe,
        .footer td {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     TYPOGRAPHY ------------------------------------- */

        h1,
        h2,
        h3 {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            color: #000;
            margin: 40px 0 0;
            line-height: 1.2;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        h4 {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        p,
        ul,
        ol {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        p li,
        ul li,
        ol li {
            margin-left: 5px;
            list-style-position: inside;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     LINKS & BUTTONS ------------------------------------- */

        a {
            color: #1ab394;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .btn-primary {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #1ab394;
            border: solid #1ab394;
            border-width: 5px 10px;
            line-height: 2;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     OTHER STYLES THAT MIGHT BE USEFUL ------------------------------------- */

        .last {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .first {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .aligncenter {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .alignright {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .alignleft {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     ALERTS     Change the class depending on warning email, good email or bad email ------------------------------------- */

        .alert {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 500;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
        }

        .alert a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .alert.alert-warning {
            background: #f8ac59;
        }

        .alert.alert-bad {
            background: #ed5565;
        }

        .alert.alert-good {
            background: #1ab394;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     INVOICE     Styles for the billing table ------------------------------------- */

        .invoice {
            margin: 40px auto;
            text-align: left;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .invoice td {
            padding: 1px 0;
        }

        .invoice .invoice-items {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .invoice .invoice-items td {
            border-top: #eee 1px solid;
            padding-left: 1px;
        }

        .invoice .invoice-items .total td {
            border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        /* -------------------------------------     RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE FRIENDLY STYLES ------------------------------------- */

        @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
            h1,
            h2,
            h3,
            h4 {
                font-weight: 600 !important;
                margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 22px !important;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size: 18px !important;
            }
            h3 {
                font-size: 16px !important;
            }
            .container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .content,
            .content-wrap {
                padding: 10px !important;
            }
            .invoice {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        .celulasValores {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .bordas-left {
            border-top-left-radius: 40%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 40%;
        }

        .bordas-right {
            border-top-right-radius: 40%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 40%;
        }

        .total {
            border-color: #ddd;
        }

        .tableValores table {
            border-spacing: 5px;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;

        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 360px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 12px 16px;
            z-index: 1;

        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;

        }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  TOTAL:
  <div class="dropdown-content">



    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Josh
          </td>
          <td>
            <div aria-label="Basic example" id="Number1">
              <table class="tableValores">
                <tr>
                  <td title="15 Dias" class="celulasValores bordas-left" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center;">16</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores" title="3 Dias" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">6</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores" title="Hoje" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">4</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores bordas-right" title="Último dia" style="padding: 2px 5px;align: center">0</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="alignright" class="total">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
              <table class="tableValores">
                <tr>
                  <td title="Atrasado após a Ação" class="celulasValores bordas-left" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">26</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores" title="Atrasado após a Meta" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">0</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores bordas-right" title="Atrasado após o Vencimento" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">292</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="alignright" class="total">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
              <table class="tableValores">
                <tr>
                  <td title="Aguardando Solicitação" class="celulasValores bordas-left" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">0</td>
                  <td class="celulasValores bordas-right" title="Retificando" style="padding: 2px 5px;align:center">0</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder Rafael. No caso, vou responder em português porque vi que é brasuca. Então a minha dúvida é como colocar o texto Josh e a div Number 1 na mesma linha.

Comment: Só colocar o nome dentro de um `<td>`. Se quiser coloca uma classe pra poder mudar o estilo mais fácil. Qq coisa é só falar Rafa!